# IIS Advanced Logging - Error with Configuration Editor script

Tags: powershell, iis, appcmd

I'm writing a PowerShell script to make some modifications to the Advanced Logging that's already in place on a few servers. The main issue I'm having is with the command below that was generated using Configuration Editor:

```
.\appcmd.exe set config "wh01-02.testlab.com" -section:system.webServer/advancedLogging/server /+"logDefinitions.[baseFileName='Log404'].filter.condition.[operator='0'].[field='Status',operator='Equals',value='404']" /commit:apphost
```

When I run this script, I get the following error:

```
ERROR ( message:Cannot find requested collection element. )
```

Kinda stumped on this one. Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, figured it out. Looks like I needed to create the 'And' operator first, then run the command:

```
.\appcmd.exe set config "wh01-02.testlab.com" -section:system.webServer/advancedLogging/server /+"logDefinitions.[baseFileName='Log404'].filter.condition.[operator='And']" /commit:apphost
.\appcmd.exe set config "wh01-02.testlab.com" -section:system.webServer/advancedLogging/server /+"logDefinitions.[baseFileName='Log404'].filter.condition.[operator='And'].[field='Status',operator='Equals',value='404',caseSensitive='False',regularExpression='False']" /commit:apphost
```